# Using matched pattern in external command

Tags: regex, vim

I'd like to define a mapping in vim which searches for a special place in the file (using a regex) and than executes an external command that depends on the matched pattern. I.e. I'm thinking about something like:

```
:g/set\ "\(.*\)"/!echo 'bla '\1' blubb' > file
```

or

```
:g:set\ "\(.*\)":call system("echo 'bla ". submatch(0) ." blubb' > file")
```

Here my aim is to search in my file for a line like

```
set "x=3"
```

and to create a new file with the content:

```
bla x=3 blubb
```

Unfortunately both tries (and several other ones) are not working. Thanks!

Edit: Adding the following to my .vimrc also didn't work:

```
:map <F4> :g:set\ "\(.*\)":call Gnutex(submatch(1))
function Gnutex(str)
   return system("echo 'bla ". a:str ." blubb' > file")
endfunction
```

Edit:
Working solution (together with the function from before):

```
:% s/set\ output\ "\(.*\)"/\=[submatch(0), Gnutex(submatch(1))][0]/
```

I think there are better solutions but this worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\1` and `submatch(0)` expressions are available as part of the `:s` command.  They are not automatically available for the `:g` command.

Something like

```
:g/set ".*"/execute "!echo 'bla" matchstr(getline("."), 'set "\zs.*\ze"') "blubb' > file"
```

should work.  (I tested without the "> file" part.)

Note that you do not have to escape " " (space) as part of a regular expression.

The key thing is that the part after `:g/<pattern>/` should be an ex command that will do what you want.  In this case, I grab the current line with `getline()`, munge it with `matchstr()` (simpler but less flexible than `substitute()`) and `:execute` the result.

You should be able to do something similar with `:call system()`.

I think that `:g` sets the search register, so you might avoid writing out your regular expression twice by using `@/` in the `matchstr()` or `substitute()` call.  In my example above, I removed the `\(`grouping`\)` characters, but you should restore them if you want to try this approach.